# log incoming ip addresses in web.py

Tags: python, web.py

I'd like to log the IP addresses of machines that access my web.py application.  How can I access this data within the web.py framework?  I'm happy to send the address to my own logger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `web.ctx['ip']` to get the remote ip address. Here is a link which [explains what's in the context](http://webpy.org/cookbook/ctx).