# Using web.py how can I get someone's IP when they visit my page

Tags: python, ip, web.py

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347484/log-incoming-ip-addresses-in-web-py) which seems to be what I'm looking for.

It says to use `web.ctx['ip']`

But I cant get it to work right, all I want is the IP of the visitor in a variable. So far I've been trying this:

```
import web

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        return "Hello, world!"
        return web.ctx['ip'] #Trying to get it to just *show* so
                             #I can put it into a variable

        print web.ctx['ip'] #Nothing happens here either

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

Thanks in advance, I think I'm close, I just need a little help. Maybe I need to import something else?

Comment: The first `return ''Hello, world!''` is exiting your function `GET(self)` before executing what's after it (`return` means exit from this function back to where it was called), comment out that first `return "Hello, world!"` expression and put `print web.ctx['ip']` before `return web.ctx['ip']`

Comment: Thank you so much! I cant believe I didn't realize that at first, I feel like an idiot now. It works now! Can you accept comments as answered? This fixed my problem.

Comment: I'll post it as answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning before even getting the `IP` address, Just re-order your code to the following way and remove `return "Hello, world!"` :

```
class index:
    def GET(self):
        print web.ctx['ip'] 
        return web.ctx['ip']
```